# How to use elements of an array?

Tags: c, arrays, stm32, hal

I am taking string data from serial port using these commands:

```
int k;
for(k=0;k<100;k++){
  buf[0]=0;
  HAL_UART_Receive(&huart2,buf,1, 100);
  aRxBuffer[k]=buf[0];
}
HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2,aRxBuffer, 100, 100);
```

and here is reading message:

```
#TPS#TP10#47#100#1.02#3.3#1.04#
```

I want to use datas between two "#" symbols.For example;
- TPS is my method name I want to use this data like this

```
if(method=='TPS'){
  dosomething();
}
```

And also 47 is my value of resistance. I will use this value in some calculations.But it is string not integer.

How can I compare my data in If Statement?

How can I transform my data from string to ingeter?

Comment: Read the chapter dealing with strings in your C textbook, You need to parse your string. What have you tried ?

Comment: I try to understand which method can I use. Do I need to parse my string for my first question or just second question?

Comment: You need to parse the string into "tokens" you need to analyze. One of these "tokens" can be a decimal value represented as string - you want to convert that token in integer format, for example using atoi(), and then analyze/perform on it.

Comment: `HAL_UART_Receive(&huart2,buf,1, 100);
  aRxBuffer[k]=buf[0];` How does this make any sense? Shouldn't you rather read the whole buffer first, then copy it?

Comment: I am new in programming.Maybe I am wrong,I am not sure

Answer (score 1):

If the # is your deliminator, you can parse the tokens like this:

```
char str[80] = "#TPS#TP10#47#100#1.02#3.3#1.04#";
const char s[2] = "#";
char *token;

/* get the first token */
token = strtok(str, s);

/* walk through other tokens */
while( token != NULL ) 
{
   printf( " %s\n", token );

   token = strtok(NULL, s);
}
```

To convert a string to number use atoi for int, atof for float.
For more questions on these work, just google them and find their definitions in the c/c++ specifications